# How to handle KieBase?

Tags: drools, kie

I am building an application which uses drools 7.47.0, this application creates drools packages dynamically and executes the packages.
The same package can be executed if it has already been built. The packages have versions and can be updated. If updated the new version would have to be build and executed existing running session would not be affected by this change in version.

These packages could be executed independently or multiple packages can be combined and executed.

```
Package 1: com.somepackage.p1
Package 2: com.somepackage.p2
Package 3: com.somepackage.p3

Execution
Scenario 1: com.somepackage.p1 
Scenario 2: com.somepackage.p1 & com.somepackage.p2
Scenario 3: com.somepackage.p1 & com.somepackage.p2 & com.somepackage.p3
```

Due to performance as suggested by drools documentation it is better to cache the KieBase.
So we were planning to build the KieBase for each package 1 KieBase.

**How do we combine KieBases at runtime?**
I tried the following

1. Creating KieModuleModels

```java
KieModuleModel module = ks.newKieModuleModel();
KieBaseModel baseModel = module.newKieBaseModel(some-dynamic-name);
.....
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
ReleaseId rid = ks.newReleaseId(release-id);
// Iteratively include all the individual KieBases
for(...){
   baseModel.addInclude(r);
}
 kfs.generateAndWritePomXML(rid);
 kfs.writeKModuleXML(module.toXML());
 KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
// the build this and extract the session from the Kie Container
```

2. Create KieBase

```java
InternalKnowledgeBase kbase = (InternalKnowledgeBase) (kBaseConfig == null ? KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase() : KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(kBaseConfig));

// Create a session from this and locally in memory cache the KieBase
```

The problem i see with this is that the there would be multiple combinations in memory and if any particular version changes that would have to be internally managed.

Need some inputs on how we can build and manage?

Comment: it seems like you're using packages instead of ruleflow-group, can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The objective that i have is that the rules (grouped within packages) are created dynamically and stored in a database. Based on the particular request the rules are picked grouped and executed. Since i do not want to build the KBase again and again due to performance i wanted know what is the best way to keep building knowledge.

Comment: As long as you want "dynamic" KieBases with custom sets of rules, you're going to have to take the performance hit of regenerating the KieBase every time. A better way to do it would be to write your rules in such a way that you can run all of your requests against them. Basically move the logic which you use to identify the rules in the database to be in the rules themselves. You may want to consider agenda groups or ruleflow groups.